# Make the size of a System.Windows.Forms.Control dependent on the size of the parent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to make some controls (specifically: Button, Label and Panel) to become dependent on the size of their parent. So a button might be 0.1 times the width of the parent, 0.05 the height, and be positioned in 0.3 times the width and 0.2 times the height. 
Now I have 2 problems:

First I want to change the behaviour of the Control class into a sort of 'relative size and relative position'-Control. This would be very easy if the Control class had an 'onParentResized' method I could override, but it hasn't. So now my solution is this

```
class RelativeControl : Control
{
    Control previousParent;
    double relativeWidth, relativeHeight, relativeX, relativeY;    

    public RelativeControl(double RelativeWidth, double RelativeHeight, double RelativeX, double RelativeY)
    {
        // the arguments need to be between 0 and 1 normally, or the control is 
        // garanteed to be partially offscreen
        this.relativeWidth = RelativeWidth;
        this.relativeHeight = RelativeHeight;
        this.relativeX = RelativeX;
        this.relativeY = RelativeY;
    }

    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(previousParent != null)
        {
            previousParent.Resize -= new EventHandler(parentResized);
        }
        if(this.Parent != null)
        {
            this.Parent.Resize += parentResized;
        }
        this.previousParent = this.Parent;
    }

    private void parentResized(Object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = (int)(this.Parent.Width * this.relativeWidth);
        this.Height = (int)(this.Parent.Width * this.relativeHeight);

        this.Location = new Point((int)(this.Parent.Width * this.relativeX), (int)(this.Parent.Height * this.relativeY));
    }
}
```

Is this a good solution?

Second problem: I want to make the Button-class (as well as the Panel and Label class) to extend this new version of control. However this isn't possible as far as I know. My only option seems to be to make 3 classes and literally find-and-replace 'Control' by "Label", "Button" and "Panel" to get the result I want.

What should I be doing here?

Comment: Seems like you would be better off having the form respond to resize events and then send a `ParentResized` event to each of its child controls. That would certainly be much easier than trying to redesign the entire UI library.

Comment: Well, that way the logic for resizing the controls becomes the job of the parent, which makes for high coupling between parent and child. This can lead to problems, because the resize event can (and in my experience: will) fire before the constructor is finished initialising all the controls. That way I end up with a null-pointer exception in the resize methode.

Comment: Ouch, you got that *exactly* backwards.  A child should never know anything about its parent.  The parent has **lots** of knowledge about the child, it creates it, gives it its properties, subscribes its events.  OnParentChanged is only ever used to implement *ambient properties*, like Font or BackColor.  That's quite rare, certainly never appropriate for Size or Location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after TableLayoutPanel control. 
Happily on .NET platform  do not have to worry anymore about child controls resizing or repositioning to the parent. 
You have to make extensive use of the Dock and Anchor properties of the child controls. 
You can start with the links but there are many tutorials about them on the web.

[TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Anchor and Dock Child Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171691%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Create a Resizable Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4d31tbk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I am playing with TableLayoutPanels and anchors as we speak.